# Get the rel attribute using Jquery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes with different rel values. My following jquery code is giving my undefined.

```
var checked_keys=[];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, value){
    checked_keys.push( value.attr('rel') );
});
```

However, If I use "this", it works.

```
var checked_keys=[];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    checked_keys.push( $(this).attr('rel') );
});
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between .each with **value** and .each with **$(this)** ?

Comment: Did you try `$(value)` instead of `value`? May be value in returning javascript element and not jQuery element. Since `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")[0]` will return a javascript element.

Comment: `value` and `this` refers to the plain DOM element Object, Not a Jquery Object. `$(value) === $(this)` and `value === this`. Recreating a jQuery object could be expensive if simple operations is your target, you could also go with `value.getAttribute("rel")`

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, the `$.each` method has a callback that return the index and the DOM node, and the latter is the native DOM node, not wrapped in jQuery, so it needs to be wrapped to work with jQuery methods like `attr()`, otherwise you'd have to use native methods like `getAttribute('rel')`

```
var checked_keys=[];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, value){
    checked_keys.push( $(value).attr('rel') );
});
```

As a sidenote, there's also a `$.map` method, that seems more appropriate

```
var checked_keys = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function(index, value){
    return $(value).attr('rel');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you log a jQuery object, you can see that all the selected elements are listed out numerically in an Array-style fashion.

```
var domElement = jqueryObject[0];//returns the first element of the jquerycollection
```

When you use the **.each** function, it will pass the native domElement as the value parameter, and not a jQuery object of that element.
This means you have to wrap the domElement with jquery like this.

```
$(domElement).attr('rel');
```

This makes your code look like this.

```
var checked_keys=[];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, vale){
    checked_keys.push( $(value).attr('rel') );
});
```